# Alterar Dinamicamente Bar Percentage

Tags: php, jquery

Eu tenho esta bar percentage e queria alterar dinamicamente o valor dela só que não estou a conseguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da Bar

```
<script>
$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(function () {
  var progress = $(this);
  var percentage = Math.ceil($(this).attr('data-percentage'));
  $({countNum: 0}).animate({countNum: percentage}, {
    duration: 2000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      // What todo on every count
      var pct = Math.floor(this.countNum) + '%';
      progress.text(pct) && progress.siblings().children().css('width',pct);
    }
  });
});
</script>
<div id="bar-5" class="bar-main-container">
              <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="51"></div>
              <div class="bar-container">
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Código que usei para tentar alterar Dinamicamente

```
<script>
$('.bar-percentage').attr('data-percentage','60')//irá receber um valor diferente depois de efectuar cálculos
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu reformulei a sua função para dar um `load` na progressBar, dê uma olhada:

Criei a função `changePercentage()`, nela você informa a barra de progresso que deseja que aconteça o `load`. Caso informe somente a progressBar, ele irá capturar o novo valor da barra pelo atributo `data-percentage`, caso queira um novo valor que não seja o desse atributo basta coloca no segundo argumento da função.

**Exemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function changePercentage(progress) {
    var percentage = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : progress.attr('data-percentage')
    percentage = Math.floor(percentage);
    var bar = progress.siblings().children();
    bar.stop().animate({
      width: percentage * progress.width() / 100
    }, {
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        var cdt = Math.round(100 * bar.width() / progress.width());
        progress.text(cdt + "%");
      }
    });
  }

  changePercentage($('.bar-percentage')); // Captura o novo valor do data-percentage

  $('button').click(function() {
    changePercentage($('.bar-percentage'), 10); // Captura o valor do segundo argumento (10)
  });
})
```

```css
.bar-container {
  width: 100%;
  background: #c7c7c7;
  height: 30px;
}

.bar-container .bar {
  background: #333;
  height: 30px;
  width: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bar-5" class="bar-main-container">
  <div class="bar-percentage" data-percentage="51"></div>
  <div class="bar-container">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>

<button>Mudar porcentagem para 10%</button>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Fico feliz em ter ajudado.

Comment: :) tentei integrar isso no meu código e nao carrega a barra preta ;(

Comment: @MANIAMAX, acho que sei qual o problema, irei editar a resposta com uma possível solução

Comment: ok :) aparece assim http://i1069.photobucket.com/albums/u479/thepeterpah/Captura%20de%20ecra%202015-12-28%20as%2015.17.41_zpspihayoh5.png

Comment: Você criou alguma maneira para fazer com que a barra carregasse com um `onload`, sou ó colou o código?

Comment: Acrescente um `$(document).ready(..`, como na minha edição da resposta.

Comment: mesmo assim nao funciona  a plataforma em questao esta desenvolvida em extj e nao esta a aceitar o document ready

Comment: Tenho duas perguntas: O a função do botão funciona? E no exemplo do seu código, que está na pergunta, o primeiro caso com o `$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(` funcionava?

Comment: Sim com o `$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each(` funciona  com o botão também não funciona

Comment: Tente `$('.bar-percentage[data-percentage]').each( changePercentage($('.bar-percentage')))`

Comment: não funciona na mesma mas obrigado pela ajuda eu vou ver outra maneira e depois posto aqui a solução

Comment: De qualquer forma, desculpe-me, levei em consideração apenas o que estava na pergunta. Mas, boa sorte

Comment: nao precisa de pedir desculpa foi uma grande ajuda :)